# Is it possible to execute more than one sql statement using JDBC interface to hsqldb?

Tags: jdbc, hsqldb

Specifically, I run these statements:

```
    String script = String.format(
      "CREATE CACHED TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s (id VARCHAR(36), value %s, PRIMARY KEY (id));", indexName, getIndexType());
    st.execute(script);
    script = String.format("CREATE INDEX idx_%s ON %s (value);", indexName, indexName);
    st.execute(script);
```

I was wondering whether it is possible to do it with one execute command? What I tried is simply concat the two strings and execute. But hsqldb complains that the table on which an index is being created does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch09.html#create_table-section) for HSQLDB don't offer any way of specifying a table index during table creation, therefore you will have to make 2 individual calls to the database.

As an aside, I would recommend to use `PreparedStatement` to protect again SQL injection attacks. The use of placeholders eliminate the need to use `String.format`.